# How to prevent GLIBC symbols from being exported from an .so?

Tags: gcc

I am linking GLIBC statically into my .so:

> g++ -shared -o morpher.so -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-L. -Wl,--whole-archive -l:hello.o -l:libmorpher.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive

I do this to make my binary (.so) portable across different Linux distributions and versions.

However, this has an undesirable side effect: all GLIBC symbols, including e.g. malloc() and free(), are exported from my shared library:

```
$ nm morpher.so | grep free
00000000000ef520 t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_14pool4freeEPv.constprop.0
000000000008b08c t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_14pool4freeEPv.constprop.0.cold
00000000000ef710 T _ZN9__gnu_cxx9__freeresEv
00000000000ef860 T __cxa_free_dependent_exception
00000000000ef7b0 T __cxa_free_exception
                 U __freelocale@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U free@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Adding `-fvisibility=hidden` has no effect: it only works on source files at compile time.

Is there a way to prevent GLIBC and libstdc++ symbols from being exported?

Answer (score 1):

`nm` (without the `-D` option) shows the static symbol table (`.symtab`), not the dynamic symbol table (`.dynsym`). Only the dynamic symbol table is relevant to dynamic linking.

In your case, it appears that the symbols are not actually defined in the shared object.  Rather, `__freelocale` and `free` are undefined (`U`) or imported. If you build your shared object on the oldest distribution you want to support, such imports do not impact cross-distribution compatibility because glibc has a compatible ABI across distributions, and later versions support symbols from older versions.

`-static-libgcc` is about libgcc (not glibc). A lot of libgcc is always statically linked. The shared-by-default part is mostly about the unwinder, and linking that dynamically is recommended, so that the system unwinder is used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Running ```nm -D``` still shows free and malloc with 'U'. Why are they undefined? Doesn't -static-libgcc tell it to link those symbols into my .so?